# Shell scripting not giving actual response

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, scripting

```
#!/bin/sh
read name
if test "$name"=akash
then 
echo "Hello how are you"
else
echo "sorry"
```

This is my script but at both case I am getting "Hello how are you" response

Comment: Looks like Cargo-cult programming, thanks to read doc FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ | Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide | Ref: http://gnu.org/s/bash/manual | http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ | http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes | Check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `test "$name" = akash` -- spaces are important.

Comment: Maybe not worst to end with `if` and indenting code properly. Indenting is like showing a bit of respect for readers and deserve clarity/readability...

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if the single string `"$name"=akash` is empty or not. You need spaces around the `=` so that `test` sees three separate arguments.

```
if test "$name" = akash
then
```

Comment: Thanks brother . This sloved my problem.